# Check that a LinkedList contains all the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, iteration

I would like to write a method `public boolean containsArray(int[] arr)` which returns `true` if **all** the elements of the array are in the list, otherwise it returns `false`.
I would like to ***only*** use the `LinkedList` class below.

```java
public class LinkedList {
    public Node head = null;

    public class Node {
        public int value;
        public Node next;

        Node(int value, Node next) {
            this.value = value
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

So far this is the code I have:

```java
public boolean containsArray(int[] arr) {
    Node tmp = head;

    while(tmp.next != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(tmp.value == arr[i] {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My idea is to iterate over the list while comparing the list values to the array elements but I am not sure how to implement this properly.

Comment: Can you tag your question with the language you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should approach this in the other direction. First iterate each value of the array, and for each value look in the linked list to find it.

Also, your `while` condition is not entirely correct: for instance, if `head` is null, the while condition will trigger an exception. You should exit the loop when `tmp` is null, not yet when `tmp.next` is null.

```java
public boolean containsArray(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int value = arr[i];
        Node tmp = head;
        while (true) {
            if (tmp == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (tmp.value == value) {
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```